# Angular: Dropdown menu closes too quickly after input loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to build a search input with a dropdown menu attached to it. I have set the menu to close when the input box loses focus.

Problem: When I click on the links inside the dropdown menu, the menu closes even before any events are registered.

```
// Search input box
<input type="text" ng-blur="lostFocus()" eva-search />

// Dropdown menu
<div class="component-styleWrap"
     ng-click="$event.stopImmediatePropagation(); $event.stopPropagation()">
  <li>Example Link</li>
  <li>Example Link</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Try the `stopPropagation` on the `li` element.

Comment: If the menu dissapears when the input loses focus, and you're clicking on a link, then your input will lose focus and the menu will go away, right? I think you need to adjust your logic.

Comment: @falsarella. Didn't work.

Comment: @la1ch3 I'm a bit stumped. None of the click/mousedown events, angular or native, seem to register before the blur. Any suggestions as how this can be structured better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to delay the effects of your call to lostFocus(), then a timeout should be enough.

```
app.controller("myController", function ($scope,  $timeout) {
    $scope.lostFocus = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            //whatever your code needs to do goes here.
        }, 100);
     });
});
```

You shouldn't really need the 100 in there. I just added that to be on the safe side. Try it without the 100 if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I use `$timeout(lostFocus)`, the ngblur doesn't run at all; `$timeout(lostFocus())` doesn't solve the original issue. Should I be putting something into the controller?

Comment: Yes, $timeout is a function which you need to inject into your controller, and add to your scope.  Otherwise it won't be available in your view. I'm going to edit the answer to just do everything in the controller. Which is simpler.

Comment: Geeze, coding on a tablet is not easy.